# Getting particular value out of a JSON object in an array

Tags: javascript, json, powershell

Getting particular out of a JSON object in an array. Where I have two keys with the same name, will vary their position each time " "name" field for the car may be in different position.
How to get just the Redcar(Redcar is not constant) if its position change

```
{
    "links": [],
    "content": [
        {
          "name": "Redcar",
          "color":"red"
         },
        {
         "name":"Eric",
          "Age":"25"
       }
      ]
}
```

Comment: `myJsonObj.content[0].name`? are you always trying to get the Redcar object ?

Comment: Yes the Redcar object be in different position(either 1 or 0)

Comment: Please create a [mcve] with proper inputs, expected output with a clear problem statement. What exactly do you mean by *"name field for the car may be in different position* and *"redcar will vary for every iteration"*. Your question is unclear

Answer (score 1):

Use `Array.find()`

```js
let data = {
  "links": [],
  "content": [
      {
        "name": "Redcar",
        "color":"red"
      },
      {
       "name":"Eric",
       "Age":"25"
      }
   ]
}

let car = data.content.find(x => {return x.name == "Redcar"});

console.log(car);
```

Comment: redcar will vary for every iteration or the API call

Comment: @karan what do you mean it will *vary*? Be specific.

Comment: redcar might be changed to truck,van,SUV...etc

Comment: @karan Okay well maybe you should have added that part into your question. You can't find something in an array if you don't know what you're looking for. As the question sits, I've given you an acceptable answer.

Answer (score 0):

If the position can change then you will want to search the array with .find()

```
let theRedCar = array.content.find( item => item.name === "Redcar" )

// theRedCar = { name: 'Redcar', color: 'red' }
```

Comment: redcar will vary for every iteration or the API call

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what you are after.

Powershell

```
## Q:\Test\2019\05\21\SO_56242505.ps1
$Json = @"
{
    "links": [],
    "content": [
        {
          "name": "Redcar",
          "color":"red"
         },
        {
         "name":"Eric",
          "Age":"25"
       }
      ]
}
"@ | ConvertFrom-Json

$Json.content | Where-Object Name -eq 'Redcar'
```

Sample output

```
name   color
----   -----
Redcar red
```